# Unable to start Cassandra DataStax DDC Server

Tags: windows, cassandra

I have a fresh installation of Cassandra 3.7 with DatStax DDC in Windows. I am trying to start the Cassandra database as a service.I am using `net start DataStax_DDC_Server` to start the service. The service is not starting and exiting without reporting an error. I am getting the following error in the logs.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create failed snapshot tracking file [C:\Cassandra\.toDelete]. Aborting
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.WindowsFailedSnapshotTracker.deleteOldSnapshots(WindowsFailedSnapshotTracker.java:99)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:177)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:585)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:714)
```

What is causing this error and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Look at the logs in the installation folder. E.g. `c:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\logs`.

The `datastax_ddc_server-stderr.xxxxx.log` will give you details about what the problem is. For me the error was `cdc_raw_directory is missing and -Dcassandra.storagedir is not set` so i opened `c:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra\conf\cassandra.yaml`, found the `cdc_raw_directory` setting and simply uncommented it.

Answer (score 4):

After fixing that you also get an Error when you will try to run cassandra.bat from command line.

it will tell you that `\conf\\\hotspot_compiler cannot be found`

Fix:
go to `C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra\conf`

modify cassandra-env.ps1

just change `CASSANDRA_CONF\conf\hotsport_compiler`
to `CASSANDRA_HOMEconf\hotsport_compiler`

WITHOUT the backslash... this is not a typo ^^

finally cassandra.bat will start and cqlshell will work.

.. then close the command window where you started cassandra.bat (as admin) press CONTROL+C

..and finally you can start the service as admin: net start DataStax_DDC_Server

Comment: thanks. It worked. Surprisingly `cassandra` was working earlier and suddenly I started getting this error. Could you please explain what might have caused the issue and how your solution fixes the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the process that i followed to get my cqlsh working on windows 10 (64 bit)

Msi Installation file used : datastax-ddc-64bit-3.9.0

After i have installed datastax: 
1) Opened cqlsh, it started closing on me. 
2) researched answers in stack overflow and found that i need to add raw directory. 
3) Based on TugboatCaptain answer I enclosed cdc_raw_directory based on my installation folder in conf\cassandra.yaml file
4) Opened Errlog file and noticed there is mistake showing in the path "C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\data\cdc_raw" at "\DataStax-DDC" error while scanning double quoted scalar. 
5) I removed "\" before "DataStax-DDC" from cdc_raw_directory value in conf\cassandra.yaml file  and started Datastax DDC Server 3.9.0
6) Opened again the Err file and noticed the error is shifted to "\data"
7) I removed "\" from cdc_raw_directory in conf\cassandra.yaml file and saved the file and started Datastax DDC Server 3.9.0
8) Opened again the Err file and noticed the error is shifted to "\data"
9) repeated the process of removing "\" and saved the file until i was able to start the service. 
10) Finally my service started, Hope this helps and also attached screenshots from my pc.

Finally my cdc_raw_directory value looked like below:

[Final Image from "conf\cassandra.yaml" once my service has started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3j3O.png)

[This is the my cqsl shell screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHZ26.png)

[Mylog file(logs\datastax_ddc_server-stderr.2019-03-24.log) screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVgZf.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (I'd start and it automatically says service stopped). I got it fixed as follows:

go to C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra\conf
edit cassandra.yaml

change

## cdc_raw_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/cdc_raw

to:
cdc_raw_directory: "C:/Program Files/DataStax-DDC/data/cdc_raw"

Make sure that there are no spaces before "cdc_raw_directory" i.e. not " cdc_raw_directory" because Python is space sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Try running the CMD prompt as administrator, that fixed the problem for me.